# How to access value of time node in a shader created by Reality Composer Pro?

Tags: swift, realitykit, shader-graph, reality-composer-pro

I am creating a shader in Reality Kit Pro that sets a material's opacity
based on the texture coordinate y-value and how much time has elapsed
since `TimeStart`. The `Time` node below is the current ``animation time:''

[image]

In my Swift code I want to set the `TimeStart` parameter to initiate the animation.
The problem is I do not know "what time it is" according to the `Time` node.
For example, if I want to start my animation in 3 seconds from the current time what
value of the `TimeStart` parameter should I use?